# Qual argumento tem prioridade em :not() quando os seletores tiver a mesma especificidade?

Tags: css

Eu recentemente estou me aprofundando na *cascata do CSS* e uma parte que não estou entendendo como funciona é a especificidade dos argumentos da pseudoclasse [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). Para ilustrar a minha dúvida, no exemplo abaixo existem dois seletores diferentes e com especificidades também diferentes passados como argumentos para `:not()`:

```css
a:not(#my-id, .my-class) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="my-id" class="my-class" href="#">My link text</a>
```

A pseudoclasse `:not()` em si não possui especificidade, mas sim, os seletores passados como argumentos. No entanto, de acordo com o que diz o [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Description) a respeito da pseudoclasse `:not()`:

<sub>Do inguês</sub>

> The specificity of the `:not()` pseudo-class is replaced by the specificity of the most specific selector in its comma-separated argument of selectors; providing the same specificity as if it had been written `:not(:is(argument))`.

<sub>Do português</sub>

> A especificidade de `:not()` pseudoclasse é substituída pela especificidade do seletor mais específico em seu argumento separado por vírgulas de seletores; fornecendo a mesma especificidade como se tivesse sido escrito `:not(:is(argument))`.

Isso significa, que no exemplo anterior, o id (`#my-id`) vai ser levado em consideração no cálculo da especificidade, justamente porque ele é mais específico. Já a classe (`.my-class`) será ignorada e não será incluída no cálculo da especificidade.

Ou seja, essa regra terá **1-0-1** de especificidade:

- **1** = Existe um seletor de id (`#my-id`).
- **0** = Não existe nenhuma pseudoclasse já que `:not()` não tem especificidade.
- **1** = Existe um seletor de elemento (`a`).

Até aqui, tudo ótimo! Porém, ao trocar os seletores com o mesmo peso de especificidade, qual seletor teria mais especificidade o primeiro ou último, passados como argumentos dentro de `:not()`?

Como, por exemplo:

```css
a:not(.my-class, [href]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="my-class" href="#">My link text</a>
```

Tanto o seletor de classe (`.my-class`) e de atributo (`[href]`) possuem a mesma especificidade e para referência a especificidade seria **0-1-1** ou algo como:

- **0** = Não existe nenhum seletor de id.
- **1** = "Eu não sei se é o seletor de classe (`.my-class`) ou atributo (`[href]`)".
- **1** = Existe um seletor de elemento (`a`).

E aqui que está a minha dúvida, **quem teve prioridade para ser incluído no cálculo da especificidade** o seletor de classe, que está sendo aplicado da esquerda (`.my-class`) para a direita (`[href]`) ou o seletor de atributo que está sendo aplicado da direita (`[href]`) para esquerda (`.my-class`)? E quando existir mais do que dois seletores passados como argumentos em `:not()` quem será aplicado na especificidade?

Comment: Faz diferença? Considerando o trecho que você citou da MDN, se o `:not` inteiro assuma a especificidade do seletor mais específico lá dentro, só importa qual é o valor especificidade, não o seletor. Se tem dois lá dentro com a mesma especificidade, o `:not` assume essa especificidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto, no caso do primeiro exemplo da minha pergunta a especificidade é **1-0-1** ou seja, você consegue perceber que a especificidade do seletor de ID foi levada em consideração, porém você quer dizer que quando dois seletores tiverem o mesmo peso de especificidade dentro de `:not()`, tanto faz o valor da especificidade de ambos os seletores?

Comment: Eu acho que tem alguma coisa te confundindo. O seu primeiro exemplo, como você disse, tem especificidade 1-0-1. Se depois dele vier outro seletor que se aplica ao mesmo elemento e tem a mesma especificidade, vale esse segundo seletor. A especificidade só importa entre seletores. Desculpe, mas estou com dificuldade de entender direito a sua dúvida...

Comment: @bfavaretto, **1-0-1** significa que o primeiro **1** é o seletor de ID `#my-id` que vem de dentro da pseudoclasse `:not()` na regra, certo? Agora, se pegarmos o segundo exemplo da pergunta, existem dois seletores com o mesmo peso de especificidade (que são `.my-class` e `[href]`), no qual os mesmos estão dentro de `:not()` da mesma forma que foi considerado o seletor de ID no cálculo da especificidade, eu quero saber qual do segundo exemplo está sendo considerado também. Tentei ser o mais claro, mas se você não entender, eu posso tentar colocar mais detalhes novamente na pergunta.

Comment: Então, tanto faz qual deles, importa a especificidade. Se os dois lá dentro têm a mesma especificidade, essa será a especificidade trazida pelo not.

Comment: @bfavaretto, até aí entendi! Mas e se eu usar como referência **0-1-1** que nem o segundo exemplo da pergunta, o mais correto é eu dizer que o peso da especificidade (o número **1** entre **0** e **1**) está vindo diretamente de `:not()`?

Comment: É correto dizer que o not "vale" `0 1 0`. Porque esse é o maior valor de especificidade que tem lá dentro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145011/discussion-between-leandro-and-bfavaretto).